# ActiveMQ Artemis HA with split-brain avoidance

Tags: high-availability, activemq-artemis

Context:

I currently have a working replication based HA setup, with the master like:

ha-policy/replication/master ....

and slave:

ha-policy/replication/slave ....

with appropriate cluster-connections setup.. (I'm using static connectors)

My understanding is that this represents a single live/backup pair.

In the network isolation documentation, both in the Quorum Voting and the Backup Voting section it states that the minimum number of live/backup pairs needed is 3.

(Note I do not wish to use the new experimental pluggable quorum vote feature.)

My question is:

What does configuration of 3 such live/backup pairs look like?
Is it via use of group-name and appropriate cluster-connections? I'm not sure what goes where so that we have 3 pairs that know about each other.
I couldn't find an example in the examples folder of the source code.

Finally, from a deployment topology perspective, would having 3 servers, s1,s2,s3, with the master/slaves deployed as follows, provide HA with split-brain avoidance:

s1: Master1, Slave3

s2: Master2, Slave1

s3: Master3, Slave2

Comment: Did you get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to do anything special to get 3 HA broker pairs. You can just repeat what you already did for the first pair two more times. Once you start all six brokers up they will automatically pair up into 3 pairs.

However, most folks want something more deterministic so they "group" pairs of brokers together via the configuration.

Both of these options are discussed in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html#data-replication) which states:

> Within a cluster, there are two ways that a backup server will locate a live server to replicate from, these are:
>
> - `specifying a node group`. You can specify a group of live servers that a backup server can connect to. This is done by configuring `group-name` in either the `master` or the `slave` element of the `broker.xml`. A Backup server will only connect to a live server that shares the same node group name
> - `connecting to any live`. This will be the behaviour if `group-name` is not configured allowing a backup server to connect to any live server

Comment: ok so assuming I repeat the first pair 2 more times - they are now 3 separate pairs. I would then need to have the 3 masters know about each other? So maybe a node group that contains just the 3 masters?

Comment: The masters should know about each other via the cluster-connection (i.e. via `discovery-group-ref` or `static-connectors`). You can find more information in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html#configuring-cluster-connections).

Answer (score 0):

Posting a concrete example for further review and editing until correct. See other answers for extra context.

This is an attempt to apply Justins responses in original question to real config.

This config is attempting to create 3 HA broker pairs - 3 masters, each with their own slave. The 3 master know about each other, but not the masters slaves.

Master-1 (tcp://master1:61616)

```
  <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="cluster">
        <connector-ref>connector-self</connector-ref>
        <static-connectors>
           <connector-ref>connector-slave1</connector-ref>
           <connector-ref>connector-master2</connector-ref>
           <connector-ref>connector-master3</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
     </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>
  
  <connectors>
    <connector name="connector-self">tcp://master1:61616</connector>
    <connector name="connector-slave1">tcp://slave1:61626</connector>
    <connector name="connector-master2">tcp://master2:61617</connector> 
    <connector name="connector-master3">tcp://master3:61618</connector>          
  </connectors>

  <ha-policy>
     <replication>
        <master>
           <!--we need this for auto failback-->
           <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
           <group-name>master-1-pair</group-name>
        </master>
     </replication>
  </ha-policy>
```

Slave-1 (tcp://slave1:61626)

```
  <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="cluster">
        <connector-ref>connector-self</connector-ref>
        <static-connectors>
           <connector-ref>connector-master1</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
     </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>

  <connectors>
     <connector name="connector-self">tcp://slave1:61626</connector>
     <connector name="connector-master1">tcp://master1:61616</connector>
  </connectors>

  <ha-policy>
     <replication>
        <slave>
           <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
           <group-name>master-1-pair</group-name>              
        </slave>
     </replication>
  </ha-policy>
```

Master-2 (tcp://master2:61617)

```
  <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="cluster">
        <connector-ref>connector-self</connector-ref>
        <static-connectors>
           <connector-ref>connector-slave2</connector-ref>
           <connector-ref>connector-master1</connector-ref>
           <connector-ref>connector-master3</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
     </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>
  
  <connectors>
    <connector name="connector-self">tcp://master2:61617</connector>
    <connector name="connector-slave2">tcp://slave2:61627</connector>
    <connector name="connector-master1">tcp://master1:61616</connector> 
    <connector name="connector-master3">tcp://master3:61618</connector>          
  </connectors>

  <ha-policy>
     <replication>
        <master>
           <!--we need this for auto failback-->
           <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
            <group-name>master-2-pair</group-name>
        </master>
     </replication>
  </ha-policy>
```

Slave-2 (tcp://slave2:61627)

```
  <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="cluster">
        <connector-ref>connector-self</connector-ref>
        <static-connectors>
           <connector-ref>connector-master2</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
     </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>

  <connectors>
     <connector name="connector-self">tcp://slave2:61627</connector>
     <connector name="connector-master2">tcp://master2:61617</connector>
  </connectors>

  <ha-policy>
     <replication>
        <slave>
           <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
           <group-name>master-2-pair</group-name>              
        </slave>
     </replication>
  </ha-policy>
```

Master-3 (tcp://master3:61618)

```
  <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="cluster">
        <connector-ref>connector-self</connector-ref>
        <static-connectors>
           <connector-ref>connector-slave3</connector-ref>
           <connector-ref>connector-master1</connector-ref>
           <connector-ref>connector-master2</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
     </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>
  
  <connectors>
    <connector name="connector-self">tcp://master3:61618</connector>
    <connector name="connector-slave3">tcp://slave3:61628</connector>
    <connector name="connector-master1">tcp://master1:61616</connector> 
    <connector name="connector-master2">tcp://master2:61617</connector>          
  </connectors>

  <ha-policy>
     <replication>
        <master>
           <!--we need this for auto failback-->
           <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
           <group-name>master-3-pair</group-name>
        </master>
     </replication>
  </ha-policy>
```

Slave-3 (tcp://slave3:61628)

```
  <cluster-connections>
     <cluster-connection name="cluster">
        <connector-ref>connector-self</connector-ref>
        <static-connectors>
           <connector-ref>connector-master3</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
     </cluster-connection>
  </cluster-connections>

  <connectors>
     <connector name="connector-self">tcp://slave3:61628</connector>
     <connector name="connector-master3">tcp://master3:61618</connector>
  </connectors>

  <ha-policy>
     <replication>
        <slave>
           <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
           <group-name>master-3-pair</group-name>
        </slave>
     </replication>
  </ha-policy>
```